# Why Are Baseball Metaphors Popular for Corporate Jargon?

Tags: idioms, terminology, cultural-phrases

Why are sports metaphors (football, baseball) so popular in western corporate cultures? I find that sports metaphors are frequently used as popular jargon there.

It seems like they're less used in Europe. It is really hard to explain why western cultures use them so freely, and also why sports metaphors are so popular and natural to them. Why are some cultures more attracted to using them? Are people in the UK also into using sports metaphors?

Why do some cultures not use them? Is it due to some fundamental cultural difference? Like, some cultures may have trouble understanding the corporate environment in that lens or see why applying such idioms reflects deeper cultural stuff. I have a lot of trouble explaining why they are so endemic and natural in western environments, even to people who don't play sports. And why that is reflective of their cultural lens.

Comment: I'm guessing you have many football (soccer) metaphors that have made it into your lexicon and you don't even notice them.

Comment: I blame (partially) whomever came up with [*Agile*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) terminology. And *Dilbert* for popularizing it by parodying it. We really don't need to describe software or business planning with words like *sprint*, *scrum master*, or *swim lanes* … and yet it's become standard in many corporations.

Comment: @JasonBassford - The terminology has been around a lot longer than Agile or Dilbert.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=out+of+the+ballpark%2Csticky+wicket&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20the%20ballpark%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csticky%20wicket%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @HotLicks Sure, *informally*. But it's now established itself as *formal* corporate language. It's no longer a personal choice in those companies. If you use Agile, you have to use the terminology too.

Comment: @JasonBassford - I'm sure it's been popular in corporate boardrooms since forever.  Part of the macho culture.

Comment: I always think of this scene from The Untouchables when baseball jargon comes up. https://youtu.be/QHH9EYZHoVU

Comment: And I spent over 40 years in computer engineering and programming and never used "swim lane" (though "sprint" was used occasionally, in a very generic sense, and we had weekly "scrums" for about 6 months).

Comment: @DonaldHosek - Yeah, I saw double entendre for the baseball bat even before it happened.

Comment: @dregg while my ancestry is Czech/Slovene, I was born in the US and have lived there my whole life.

Comment: Why do you think they are less popular in Europe?

Comment: @Hachi I haven't heard anyone use them and colleagues appear to be unfamiliar with them? Do you think they're popular? Have you heard them used and in what context? Which country?

Comment: You mean American  football?

Comment: Why Sports Are a Terrible Metaphor for Business - https://hbr.org/2017/02/why-sports-are-a-terrible-metaphor-for-business

Comment: @Hachi or any sports

Comment: Sports is a metaphor for war, and competition. Business is competition, or at least that's the theory. It's natural to turn to sport metaphors in business, when the spirit is aimed at competitors. If the culture is different, though -- if managers are expected to be good at something besides inspiring, for instance -- sports might not be the metaphor of choice.

Comment: I'm CV'ing for several reasons. First, this seems to ask about Western culture in general (e.g., "western corporate cultures") and not the English language specifically. Second, the title (which specifies baseball) doesn't agree with the body (which is about sports more broadly). Third, OP seems to distinguish between the West (where these metaphors are "so popular") and Europe (where "they're less used") although Europe is generally considered to be part of the West. There are other problems with this question, too, but I think that's enough to make my point.

Answer (score 1):

The paper ["Foul Play: Sports Metaphors as Public Doublespeak"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/375994) advances one theory about why these metaphors are so common in the US. I can best explain the matter by quoting that paper at length:

> [Sports] fit philosophically with the widely accepted American dream of open competition in a free market economy. Americans believe in competition, foster it, and encourage it. They live by its rules. No wonder the language of athletic competition has found its way as metaphor in to every aspect of American life. [....]
>
> By making analogies to sports, business convinces the outside world that its decisions aren't truly consequential: they are "games" executed by good "team players." The fact that dollars and human lives may also be involved is not included when the sports metaphor is used [....]
>
> Sports are an acceptable form of releasing aggressive impulses; if business uses the sports metaphor, isn't the aggressiveness of business automatically acceptable?